# Translation per module is not working properly in magento2

Tags: translation

I need to change the "**Add to Compare**" string to "**Compare**" in the product detail page alone. So I put "Add to Compare", "Compare" in **app/code/Magento/Catalog/i18n/en_US.csv** file and put setup upgrade and deploy. but It not changed in pdp.

Comment: voting to close.

Comment: hi @ananhan, please visit the site for magento , https://magento.stackexchange.com/